# java inheriting random class and the caller

Tags: java, random

I have the following code regarding inherting the Random class but I cannot figure out what is happening.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Chance extends Random{

    public int throwDie(){      
        return (1 + nextInt(6));
    }
}
```

in the throuDie method, the "nextInt" method has no caller. I do not understand how can it run like this. I did not even create a Chance object nor a Random object.

can someone explain?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what a static method is?

Comment: Looks like you need to read a tutorial on inheritance, such as https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: I know what static method is but if you want to use the method "nextInt" you need to create a random object. This method in the Random class is clearly not a static method.

Answer (score 0):

class Random has a nextInt(int bound) instance method

When you extend class Chance from Random, the new subclass inherits the nextInt method, and you may use it just as if you had declared this method within your new class.

It would be worthwhile to carefully read the description of class inheritance; there are a lot of 'gotchas' that can bite you

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know what does it mean by inheritance and static method. However, I tried and I could not call the method nextInt() without an   Object. The method is not a static one. The problem is I can call it through the inheritance class as a static method. How can this happen?